# Catching NSKeyedUnarchiver exception

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nsexception, nskeyedunarchiver

In Swift, `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)` will throw an exception if data can't be unarchived.

There are some situations where we have no guarantee if that the data is not corrupted, such as when reading from a file.

I am not aware of a try/catch mechanism in Swift, nor that I know of a method like `canUnarchive` that would help prevent the exception.

Besides implementing the try/catch in Obj-C, is there a pure Swift solution to this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you already found a solution?

Comment: Apple should have made a try/catch for swift...

Comment: same problem here, and this is crazy..

Answer (score 10):

Because `unarchiveObjectWithData()` doesn't `throw` its exception, there is currently no way to catch it in Swift (as of writing).  The iOS 9 SDK has added a new `NSKeyedUnarchiver` method `decodeTopLevelObject()` which now `throws` an error.  You can catch this with the `do`, `try`, `catch` control flow.

```
do {
    let result = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(NSData(...))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```